# Dynamically append content to an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, polling

I would like to be able to have an ajax get update the text in a span tag each time it is fired.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "JSON URL",
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(html){
      $('#status_frame_span').prepend(html.status)
      alert(html.status)
    },
    error: function(jq,stats,errmes) {
             alert("Error" + errmes);
           }
  });
```

the first time it fires, the content of the json returned from the URL is properly prepended to the span.  however for subsequent firings it is not updated.

How do I ensure that with each firing the content gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

What triggers the call to the server?  Is it a button or link inside of the HTML being updated?  if it is, the event handler may be lost when the UI is updated.  Or, something else is losing the event handler, which doesn't call the method to fire the get request, etc.

HTH.

Comment: this is inside of a rails app.  the javascript gets triggered upon initial load of the page.  within the original page are some links that load html into an iframe.  that html load triggers a new firing of the code.  I have a rabbitmq server and there is a partial that reads messages off of the queue.  I would like to simulate a web frontend to a logging system such that as new messages get injected into the queue they get displayed on the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Of course your view is updated only once: you are calling the server only once!

If, as your tags suggest, you are using [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) (please make sure that's the case, I'm not sure you have a very clear idea of what is an event, a poll and a distant call), then you need to make a new request each time you've received one!

In both your `success` and `error` handlers, you have to recursively make an AJAX call to the server. You also have to set a timeout for the calls, which could cancel them and start a new one after, for example, 30 seconds.

You should also implement some kind of throttling for recursive calls, unless you're 99.99% sure the server page will never send errors. Otherwise, you'll kill your client.

For the sake of completeness, I have to add this would be a great use-case for HTML5 [SSE](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) or [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). But they're not ready for production usage yet.

Comment: we're using socket.io in production mode without any trouble :)

Comment: Of course, if you're using a library that provides [all fallbacks](http://socket.io/#browser-support) and hides them behind a nice API, there's no problem  :)  That still doesn't mean WebSocket, as a technology, on its own, is production-ready. If you were to implement a [draft spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) in your website, you would be very disappointed with browser support and maintenance  ;)

Answer (score 0):

it does not work that way - if the success callback is called - the connection has been closed so your long polling will be dead once the request is completed.

The idea behind long polling is that you keep the connection alive. Configure your server properly so that it will hold the connection open as long as possible (set timeout as high as possible).

Here's an approach from my coffee break (not tested):

**Server**

- Every message has to end with the delimiter ::PART::
- The server must be properly configured this means set the timeout as high as possible!

**Client (Browser)**

```
// setup longpoll, check all 250ms for new data in the stream
var myPoller  = new LongPoll('some-url', 250);

// bind connection lost
myPoller.bind('longpoll:end', function(evt) {
  alert('connection lost - trying reconnect');
});

// bind error event
myPoller.bind('longpoll:error', function(evt, errmsg) {
  alert('error: ' + errmsg);
});

// bind data event
myPoller.bind('longpoll:data', function(evt, data) {
  try {
    // try to parse json
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    // prepend 
    $('#status_frame_span').prepend(data.status);
  } catch(e) {
    // invalid json
    alert('invalid json: ' + data);
  }
});
```

**longpoll.js**

```
var LongPoll = function(url, timeout) {

  // url we connect to
  this.url        = url;

  // running?
  this.isRunning  = false;

  // timer for checking the stream
  this.timer      = null;

  // the length of the received data
  this.dataLength = 0;

  /*
    The messages has to be delimited by the delimiter like:
    first data::PART::second data::PART::third data::PART::
  */

  this.delimiter = RegExp.new("::PART::", 'gm');


  // residue from previous transmission
  this.residue   = ''
};


// connect to server

LongPoll.prototype.connect = function() {

  var self = this;

  // reset data length
  this.dataLength = 0;

  // reset residue
  this.residue    = '';

  // start ajax request
  this.xhr  = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: this.url,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(){
      // the connection is dead!
      self.xhr = null;

      // trigger event 
      $(self).trigger('longpoll:end');

      // reconnect if still running
      if(self.isRunning) {
        self.connect();
      }
    },
    error: function(jq,stats,errmes) {
      // stop timer and connection
      self.stop();
      $(self).trigger('longpoll:error', errmes);
    }
  }); 
};


// process data
LongPoll.prototype.process = function(buffer) {

  var self = this;

  // check if there is anything new
  if(buffer.length > this.dataLength) {

    var newData = this.residue + buffer.substring(this.dataLength, buffer.length);

    // reset residue
    this.residue  = '';

    // store the new position
    this.dataLength = buffer.length;

    // split data
    var dataParts = newData.split(this.delimiter);

    // how many full parts?
    var fullParts = newData.match(this.delimiter).length;

    if(dataParts.length > fullParts) {
      // pop residue (incomplete message)
      this.residue += dataParts.pop();
    }    

    $.each(dataParts, function(index, part) {
      // broadcast data parts
      $(self).trigger('longpoll:data', $.trim(data));
    });    
  }
};


// check for data
LongPoll.prototype.receive = function() {

  var self = this;

  // connection still there?
  if(this.xhr) {
    // process buffer
    this.process(this.xhr.responseText);
  }  
};


// start long poll

LongPoll.prototype.start = function() {

  var self = this;

  // set flag
  this.isRunning = true;

  this.timer  = setInterval(function() { self.receive(); }, this.timeout);

  this.connect();
};

// stop long poll

LongPoll.prototype.stop = function() {

  // set flag
  this.isRunning = false;

  // clear timer 
  clearInterval(this.timer);

  if(this.xhr) {
    // abort request
    this.xhr.abort();
  }
};
```